# Delphi TTreeView: get root node count and root node by index?

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-10-seattle

Every `TTreeNode` can give me its number of direct children using `Node.Count`, and I can get any child by index using `Node[Index]`.

I am searching and searching but it seems this not possible for root nodes?? Do I really have to count them myself? And if yes, what's the most elegant way to do this both?

I was expecting some hidden *root-root-item* which just has all the *root nodes* as children, wouldn't that be helpful to be able to treat all sorts of nodes the same, i.e. for a recursive function doing something for all nodes?

Comment: What about TTreeView.Items?

Comment: It returns all nodes by *absolute* index, @MartynA

Comment: Sure, but won't one of its Items be a TreeNode with a Nil .parent?

Comment: Of course I can get the necessary information somehow from there, it just feels a little cumbersome, compared to childnodes, @MartynA

Comment: One of the nodes will return true for `IsFirstNode`.  From the OLH "IsFirstNode returns true for the first node, with no parent node or previous sibling."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `TTreeView` should have this, but it doesn't, and I don't see a good reason. However, here are some thoughts to take into account:

The data structure used in the `TTreeView` doesn't directly support counting direct children or accessing them by index, because it is a linked list where each node links to its parent, its next and previous sibling, and its first child.

For your convenience, the `TTreeNode` object is able to give you what you want, but for that it has to loop through the chain and count.

That also means, accessing all children in a for-loop is anyway not a good idea, like in the recursive function you mentioned - it would unnecessarily be a loop in a loop.

Instead, directly go through the chain using `TreeView.Items.GetFirstNode` (or `MyParentNode.getFirstChild`) and then a while loop with `Node:= Node.getNextSibling` (that also works very well for a recursive function).

Suggestion: look at the implementation in *Vcl.ComCtrls*. From there, you could also adapt the two most elegant functions you ask for, in case you still need it :)

```
type
  TTreeViewClassHelper = class helper for TTreeView
    function GetRootCount: Integer;
    function GetRootItem(Index: Integer): TTreeNode;
  end;

function TTreeViewClassHelper.GetRootCount: Integer;
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  Node:= Items.GetFirstNode;
  while Assigned(Node) do begin
    Inc(Result);
    Node:= Node.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;

function TTreeViewClassHelper.GetRootItem(Index: Integer): TTreeNode;
begin
  Result:= Items.GetFirstNode;
  while Assigned(Node) and (Index > 0) do begin
    Result:= Result.getNextSibling;
    Dec(Index);
  end;
end;
```

And just to demonstrate how you should **not** do it ;-)

```
for I:= 0 to TreeView.GetRootCount - 1 do
  with TreeView.GetRootItem(I) do
    Memo.Lines.Add(string.Join(#9, [AbsoluteIndex, Index, Text]));
```

Comment: I'd call GetFirstNode and loop with GetNextSibling.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, correct, I was accidentally looking at Vcl.ComCtrls, where TTreeNode.GetItem is done using GetFirstChild and GetNextChild... Edited.

Comment: I tried to ask a good question, and while writing it, @MartynA, I continued investigating and then didn't want to throw it away... So I posted it, already assuming that I would write the answer myself :) I've done this before and it seems some people don't like it. I really wonder why...

Comment: I don't have a problem at all with people answering their own questions, in fact I wish more people would do it when no-one else has posted an answer.  In this case, I was just curious the way you phrased you answer, referring to yourself as "you" rather than just saying words to the effect of "On furtther consideration, I believe the following answers my q ...".  That was all ...